# Error con servicio en Angular

Tags: angular

Este es el servicio donde puse algo estándar para hacer pruebas.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
// import { Admin } from '../models/admin';
import { Global } from './global';

@Injectable()

export class AdminService {
    public url: string;
    constructor(
        public _http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.url = Global.url;
    }

    getAdmin(): Observable<any> {
        // let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:4000/api/adminget/5e443138c7c5286638666900');
    }
}
```

El siguiente es mi app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Form, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing'

import { WebcamModule } from 'ngx-webcam';
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    ColorPickerModule,
    routing,
    WebcamModule,
  ],
  providers: [appRoutingProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y pues según yo lo hice correctamente, pero al momento de llamarlo en el componente de login el cuál es el siguiente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Admin } from '../../models/admin';
import { AdminService } from '../../services/admin.service';
import { Global } from '../../services/global';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public admin: Admin;

  constructor(
    private _adminService: AdminService,
    private _router: Router
  ) {
    this.admin = new Admin('', '', '', '');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    // this._adminService.getAdmin(this.admin).subscribe(
    //   res => {
    //     if (res.admin) {

    //     }
    //   },
    //   err => {
    //     console.log(<any>err);

    //   }
    // );
    console.log(this.admin);

  }

}
```

En la parte de `private _adminService: AdminService`, que es la línea 16, me marca un error y no me aparece el componente.

> NullInjectorError: No provider for AdminService!

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo, el error que presentas te dice lo que está pasando.

> No provider for AdminService!

En tu `app.module.ts`, agrega esto a **providers**:

```
providers: [
  AdminService
],
```

Recuerda que un **provider** es una instrucción para el sistema de Inyección de dependencias sobre cómo obtener un valor para una dependencia. La mayoría de las veces, estas dependencias son servicios que usted crea y proporciona.

En tu error también te marca `NullInjectorError`, esto es porque tu `AdminService` no tiene una instancia creada.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Oh rayos... odio mi vida ;u;

Comment: @Padron Estamos para ayudar. Si te ha funcionado, puedes marcar mi respuesta como la solución, de esa forma otros usuarios podrán encontrar la solución rápidamente.

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias ;n; Es que faltaban seis minutos para que pudiera darla como correcta